# Creating a frontend for vim

Tags: c, user-interface, vim

I am huge fan of vim and I use it daily for almost every editing task. I realize that vim is made to be used in terminal and that's great, because it makes it usable on servers without desktop environment etc. 
But I also like pretty applications with neat graphical interface and additional features like projects or ftp clients (I know there are vim plugins for almost anything, but I prefer comfort that for example IDEs provide), so I searched for vim-like alternatives with pretty GUI. Obviously, I ran into Sublime Text, which is almost perfect, but lacks some of the vim's power. That made me think, would it be possible to take vim's source code and build a nice frontend for it? Well.. of course it would be possible, but **my question is**, how hard and time-consuming would it be, and what would be the best approach? Or is there already such project that I haven't found?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: What about the GUI of Vim for Windows? http://www.vim.org/download.php

Comment: I know I should've mentioned gvim :) Yes I know about it, but it doesn't provide much of what I'd like.. I thought about something more like Sublime Text

Comment: There are a couple of Vim plug-ins for Visual Studio, if that's your bag.

Comment: If it's just vim key commands that you want, Sublime Text 2 has a mode called "VIntage Mode" which will emulate most of that.

Comment: Many programs have Vim plugins: for example all major IDEs.  Between that and gVim/MacVim, I'm not sure what functionality you're really missing.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: I know about all those plugins and I have tried them, I also know about Vintage mode in Sublime, but these are all just substitutes, I was thinking about building a GUI _on top of_ vim. Something that looks like Sublime Text but has REAL vim, not just a plugin.

Comment: Could you in more detail describe what 'comfort' you are missing from Vim? Vim does already have some graphical stuff (try GVim and check   `:h guioptions`), I'm sure you could change the icons and themes pretty easily if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Uh, I'm trying to :) as a scale for the comfort, let's use Sublime Text. Now I would like to build something like that on top of vim (using its source code).

Answer (score 3):

There's at least [one IDE built around Vim](http://code.google.com/p/pida/). It comes with a GUI-based file tree and symbol tree and a few other niceties but the editor component is still plain Vim, though, so there's not much "improvement" in the look & feel department.

On Mac OS X, MacVim is very well integrated in the whole Mac UX (native shortcuts, .app bundle…) but it's still Vim. There's even a fork that provides a "native" file drawer. No "improvement" to speak of there, either.

As far as I know, and besides GVim on Linux/Windows, these are the only examples of work done on the GUI side. Wait! There's also a recent QT-based project.

Whatever, what these projects do is "bolt" all kinds of GUI widgets to the Vim core and bind them to internal stuff. What you seem to have in mind is an entirely different matter. You didn't explain exactly what you wanted so I have to extrapolate a bit. I guess that you probably would like:

- roundrects
- shadows
- gradients
- animations
- GUI theming
- mouse friendliness
- smooth scrolling
- …

I'm not familiar with Vim's internals but I'm quite certain that hacking all these aspects would represent quite a large amount of work. The simple fact that Vim, either in a shell or as GVim/MacVim, draws *everything* with text, has a fairly old school imput system or isn't even multithreaded makes for a *huge* challenge, IMO.

---

About your question…

You ask how or if it would be possible to build a "nice" GUI for Vim and you propose ST2 as a baseline.

For starter, not everyone has a high opinion on ST2 itself or its look and feel. I, for one, think it's a gimmicky and inconsistent piece of shit on the UX/visual design front and an underpowered editor in general. I have a hard time imagining why anybody would think that it's somehow "nicer" than Vim on any front.

Furthermore, not everyone thinks Vim or GVim's design/UX sucks. I'd go as far as betting that most vimmers actually like it for what it is. The text-based UI has value for a lot of us and I don't think that I'm the only one who doesn't think that adding gradients, rounded corners and shadows to Vim would make it better in any way. I might be wrong, of course. As you wrote, one vim's strengths is that you can use it in a terminal. Your project - or what I think is your project - sounds a lot like adding a lot of things to GUI Vim that would make no sense whatsoever in terminal Vim. Decoupling the two sounds like a very bad and wasteful idea to me.

If you *really* want to make Vim better, may I suggest a bunch of other fronts? A unified plugin API, a better API for external languages, multithreading, modernizing the imput system… there's a lot to be done. And I'd say it's immensely more important than adding worthless eye candy.

In order to kickstart a constructive discution, you should *really* provide:

- a commented list of those niceties you would like to see in vim,
- reasoned arguments for why these niceties would be considered "improvements,
- implementation ideas.

Oh! And SO is *definetely* not the right place to discuss such things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! On the subject of ST2 - I didn't say I like it as a whole, just wanted to show some example of what I have in mind. Thanks for mentioning pida, i'll look into that.

Comment: No problem. Just saying "ST2" is not enough. Showing those examples (screenshots and all) is what you need to do.